# Lunge - Deep painful stretch in Hamstrings

Tags: pain, legs, hamstring

Lately I have been trying out some new excercises to train my legs.

One of which is the Lunge.

Now I noticed that when doing them without weight, I had no problem at all. But when I took about 10kg each hand (which should be easy since I'm not new to training legs) I had a very painful stretchy-like feeling in my hamstring.

I'm keeping my back straight and making sure that my knee doesn't come over my toes.

Is there any idea on what this might cause?

*(Personal Trainer said that form wasn't causing the pain, I switched to different hamstring excercises)*

Comment: Where did the pain happen? At the top, on the drop down, or on the way back up? Was it both hamstrings or just one?

Comment: @EricKaufman , on the way back up/at the top, both hamstrings

Answer (score -1):

No worry ivaro, you switched to 10 kgs of weights in both hands directly from null. You should have increased the weight gradually like 2.5, 5 then 10. Even though you are not a beginner still it really doesn't matter how better you are in doing other exercises... Our body react differently for different exercises. Infact this is the way our body adapts it.. But it is only correct if the intensity is increased gradually. 
My suggestion is to start doing lunges but with less weight and you'll be good to go.